# Firebase Auth does not work without Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

My app got rejected from Amazon Appstore due to an error while trying to login with Firebase AuthUI.

I decided to do some research and found out that all Amazon Fire devices run without Google Play Services. I installed a new emulator without Google services and also got an error.

The strange part is, that the version 20.0.0 of the Firebase Auth introduced a feature "[The Firebase Authentication Android library now works on devices without Google Play services.](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v20-0-0)".

Code

```
public void signIn() {
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> listProviders = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.YahooBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()
    );

    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    Intent intentSignIn = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(listProviders)
            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.login_icon)
            .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
                    "URL",
                    "URL")
            .build();
    activityResultLauncherSignIn.launch(intentSignIn);
}

// https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncherSignIn = registerForActivityResult(
        new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
        this::onSignInResult
);

private void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult firebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult) {
    IdpResponse idpResponse = firebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult.getIdpResponse();
    if (firebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
        if (firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.getEmail() != null && !firebaseUser.isEmailVerified())
            sendVerificationEmail();
    } else {
        // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
        if (idpResponse != null && idpResponse.getError() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem with Firebase authentication: " + idpResponse.getError().getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
Problem with Firebase authentication: 0

> com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: -9: Install Error(-9): The Play Store app is either not installed or not the official version.

I am using these dependencies:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the following docs:

- **[FirebaseUI for Auth Open Source Docs](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/auth/readme/)**
- **[Firebase Local Emulator Suite Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite)**

So, you need to run the emulator (if running, then ignore) and tell `AuthUI` to use the emulator that you are running.

Update the part of your code to this:

```
AuthUI authUI = AuthUI.getInstance();

// Change the ip and port accordingly. 
// I'm using the one mentioned in the docs
authUI.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099);

Intent intentSignIn = authUI.createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(listProviders)
            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.login_icon)
            .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
                    "URL",
                    "URL")
            .build();
```

See if this works.

Comment: @MihaM See if this works.

Comment: I still get the same error. I noticed that the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously(); works though, when trying to login without AuthUI.